# Client side only code in store on Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxtjs

I'm trying to migrate my Vue app to nuxt.js and running into the issue with a store module where I import a cryptography node library. This library accesses a "window" object that naturally only exists on the client side.
The very fact of this module being in the store directory crashes the app. AFAIK I can import it as a plugin in nuxt.config.js but how do I attach it to the store after that?
Thanks!

Actually, I'm not sure anymore if the error is caused by SSR, since I see it in the browser. Just thought it was the case because of the "window not defined" thing. I've also tried importing crypto-pro on a page - it gives the same error. Naturally, in a regular vue project it works fine.

Here's my store/index.js

```
import crypto from "../plugins/crypto";

export const plugins = [crypto];

export const state = () => ({

});
```

Here's the crypto.js module. The

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {createHashSignature, getHashedData, getUserCertificates, isValidSystemSetup, verifySignature } from 'crypto-pro';
import FileReader from '@tanker/file-reader';

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {some state},
    mutations: {some mutations},
    actions: {some actions}
}
```

Here's what I get when I try opening the site

ReferenceError
window is not defined

```
node_modules\crypto-pro\lib\crypto-pro.js

        define("cryptoPro", [], factory);
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["cryptoPro"] = factory();
    else
        root["cryptoPro"] = factory();
})(window, function() {
return /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
```

crypto-pro module itself is an API for working with a browser plugin that connects to the crypto provider on the user's PC.

Comment: Are there any log entries, outputs, ... you can share? Does there come any error message?

Comment: `if(process.client) { ... }` this maybe?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a plugin like this:

```
export default function ({ store }) {
  if (process.client) {
     //do something on client side
  }
}
```

Destructure `store` out of the [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought about at first but it seems my problem begins with the way crypto-pro module works in a nuxt project.